# login with Do..while loop in C

Tags: c, string, loops, do-while

I need to make a program that asks for a username and password and if they are both correct continue to a menu.
Currently inputting a **correct** username and **wrong** password for some reason still prompts me to the menu, however if i input a **wrong** username and **correct** password it doesn't .Also if i enter correct username and password from the first try, it always returns "Wrong username or password try again".Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define user "kaiti"
#define pass "123Pass!"        
int main()
{
    char username[20], password[20];

    //-----LOGIN PHASE-----
    printf("Please Enter username:");
    scanf("%s", &username);

    printf("\nPlease enter password:");
    scanf("%s", &password);
    do
    {

        printf("Wrong username or password try again!\n");

        printf("\nPlease Enter username:");
        scanf("%s", &username);

        printf("\nPlease enter password:");
        scanf("%s", &password);

    }
    while (strcmp(username, user) != 0 && strcmp(password, pass) != 0);

    printf("Correct username and password.\n\nWelcome Mrs.Kaiti!\n\nWhat would you like to do?");
    //-----END OF LOGIN PHASE-----
```

Comment: The first statement of the loop is printf("Wrong username or password try again!\n"); So what do you want?! What you do is what you get.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&username);` --> `scanf("%19s",username);`

Comment: Your logic seems a little bit flawed, wouldn't it be better to check for correct username/password *before* printing "wrong username or password"? I.e. have an ordinary `while-do` loop instead of a `do-while`?

Comment: Do you know `strcmp()` actually returns 0 if the strings match?

Comment: Well, if a wrong username or pass are given then it should direct the user to try again.However the while loop should only start when a wrong user and pass are give, not always.How do i fix that?

Comment: A `do...while` is probably better, but you want the initial prompts/reads _inside_ it, followed by a check for their correctness (which will both trigger the "Is wrong" message and make the loop repeat).  As it is, you're repeating the prompt/read code twice.

Comment: @John.E  Also in the condition of the loop there should be used the logical OR operator instead of the logical AND operator     while (strcmp(username, user) != 0 || strcmp(password, pass) != 0);

Comment: once you've got this working, it's worth looking at `crypt()` and not storing the password in plain text.

Comment: Implementing the passwords statically in code will allow anyone who is technically skilled enough to just take the credentials from the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do-while loop starts with the message

```
printf("Wrong username or password try again!\n");
```

So you always will get this message in the program independing on what the user entered.

This statement and similar statements

```
scanf("%s", &username);
           ^^^
```

should be written at least like

```
scanf("%s", username);
           ^^^
```

Though in any case this statement is unsafe because the user can overwrite the input character array.

Instead it is better to use standard function `fgets`.

This condition of the loop

```
while (strcmp(username, user) != 0 && strcmp(password, pass) != 0);
                                   ^^
```

is wrong, There should be

```
while (strcmp(username, user) != 0 || strcmp(password, pass) != 0);
                                   ^^
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USER    "kaiti"
#define PASS    "123Pass!"        

#define N   20

int main(void) 
{
    char username[N], password[N];
    int valid = 0;

    do
    {
        size_t n, m;

        //-----LOGIN PHASE-----
        printf( "Please Enter username (no more than %u symbols): ", N - 2 );
        fgets( username, N, stdin );

        printf("\nPlease enter password (no more than %u symbols): ", N - 2 );
        fgets( password, N, stdin );


        n = strcspn( username, "\n" );
        m = strcspn( password, "\n" );

        valid = username[n] == '\n' && password[m] == '\n';

        username[n] = '\0';
        password[m] = '\0';

        valid = valid && strcmp( username, USER ) == 0 && strcmp( password, PASS ) == 0;

        if ( !valid )
        {
            printf("\nWrong username or password try again!\n\n");
        }
    } while ( !valid );

    printf("Correct username and password.\n\nWelcome Mrs.Kaiti!\n\nWhat would you like to do?");
    //-----END OF LOGIN PHASE-----  return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Please Enter username (no more than 18 symbols): kaiti
Please enter password (no more than 18 symbols): 123Pass

Wrong username or password try again!

Please Enter username (no more than 18 symbols): kaiti
Please enter password (no more than 18 symbols): 123Pass!

Correct username and password.

Welcome Mrs.Kaiti!

What would you like to do?
```

In the first attempt the user entered a wrong password.

You could also restrict the number of attempts for the user introducing a counter for the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You boolean expression is wrong. The valid case is `strcmp(username, user) == 0 && strcmp(password, pass) == 0` (username and password are correct). The inversion of that is `strcmp(username, user) != 0 || strcmp(password, pass) != 0` (means "either one of the conditions is not met").

An for the second question on not showing the notification on the 1st round, you could use a simple increment like the following (`i` has to be initialized to `0`):

```
if (i++ > 0) {
  printf("Wrong username or password try again!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `while (condition) { /* body */ }` loop.

Don't use the address of the array in the `scanf` call: `scanf("%s", username);`. The array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: You are wrong. He wants a do-while loop and indeed he should use a do-while loop.

Comment: I believe the error message (invalid credentials) should appear after an error... so, ask for credentials once outside the loop, check those credentials and if wrong inform the user and get new credentials.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use a do-while-loop it will always run through the loop before checking the while condition. So it doesn't matter what you insert before your loop because it will always jump in the loop on the first run. You can solve it by using a while-loop or put everything in the do-while-loop and change it a little bit
- Your condition in the while loop is not correct. It will check the first condition `strcmp(username, user) != 0` first. If it is true it will check the second condition, but if not it will end the loop because the conditional `AND` has no chance to evaluate to true anyway. So if the username is correct this condition will evaluate to false and the password won't be evaluated. You can use a logic OR (`||`) to check both conditions. The difference between AND and OR is the following:

Deny the access if the password AND the username is wrong. -> Only deny if both are wrong

Deny the access if the password OR the username is wrong. -> Deny if one is wrong